# Adding JRE to classpath programatically with JUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I  can add a JRE in classpath programatically using

```
entries.add(JavaRuntime.getDefaultJREContainerEntry());
```

where `entries`  is a classpathyentry. Anyone know how to do this for JUnit?

Comment: Check this SO question on [loading-jars-dynamically-at-runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this one

```
IClasspathEntry junit4Entry = BuildPathSupport.getJUnit4ClasspathEntry();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I try

```
IClasspathEntry junit4Entry = BuildPathSupport.getJUnit4ClasspathEntry();
```

I get

> Discouraged access: The type 'ClasspathEntry' is not API (restriction on required library  /{path}/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.10.0.v20140604-1726.jar')

So

```
IClasspathEntry junit4Entry = JavaCore.newContainerEntry(JUnitCore.JUNIT4_CONTAINER_PATH);
```

works better, no warnings `;)`